# Env in pod is not loading as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, environment-variables

I am using below secretproviderclass and it is creating secret and loading it as an env in pod but the format is not correct.

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: pp-dev-pp-webapp
  namespace: pp-dev
spec:
  provider: aws
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: csi-secret-newrelic
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - key: NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY
      objectName: NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY
  parameters:
    objects: |
        - objectName: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1xxxxxx:secret:xxxxxxxx"
          objectAlias: "NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY"
          objectType: "secretsmanager"
```

```
..
..
..

volumes:
      - name: pod-webapp
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "pp-dev-pp-webapp"
      containers:
        - name: {{ include "helm.name" . }}
          image: {{ .Values.imageRepository }}/{{ .Values.imageName }}:{{ .Values.imageTag }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.imagePullPolicy }}
          volumeMounts:
           - name: pod-webapp
             mountPath: "/mnt"
             readOnly: true
          env:
          - name: test_name
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: csi-secret-newrelic
                key: NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY
..
..
..
```

The env is loading in below format

`test_name={"NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}`

but it should be in format

`NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Tried editing secretstoredriver and deployment by commenting out test_name reference but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to how you are referencing the secret in the `env` section of your pod.
To get the required format, refer to the key without adding the key in the environment variable name:

```
  - name: NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: csi-secret-newrelic
        key: NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY
```

This should set the env NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY with the value retrieved from the secret.

I was referring to those manifests for the sake of simplicity. Here is an example of a simple pod that takes envs from a Kubernetes secret named `db-secret`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webapp-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webapp-pod
    image: kodekloud/simple-webapp-mysql
    env:
    - name: DB_Host
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: db-secret
          key: DB_Host
    - name: DB_User
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: db-secret
          key: DB_User
    - name: DB_Password
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: db-secret
          key: DB_Password
```

Here is a simple kubernetes secret name template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  DB_Host: xxxx
  DB_User: xxxxx
  DB_Password: xxxxxx
```